# CSS How do you fit images of different aspect ratios and different sizes in a 3:1 rectangle div?

Tags: html, css, aspect-ratio, object-fit

A banner div (className `content-area-container`) is a 3:1 rectangle of 300x100 dimensions, according to wikipedia    https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Standard_web_banner_ad_sizes.svg

however, it is using `vw` units so it will grow and shrink proportionally as the webpage viewport is maximized or minimized

The div must hold 1 logo image. The logo images are of various sizes and aspect ratios. Most are rectangular, some are square, while some are very wide or have a large height

My question is how do you fit the image logo in the centre of the div, fill it and show as much as possible without compromising the aspect ratio?

The image logos should not overlap with the text & content below, and they should never exceed the maximum height of the banner div otherwise the parent div will overflow

my css and html are not making the image logos fit but rather are still in original size

```
<div className="content-area">
    <div className="content-area-container">
        <img className="logo" src={`${image_logo_url_path}`} alt="boxart" />
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.content-area {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 3;
  }


.content-area-container {
    padding: 18px 0 12px 4%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 10;
  }

  .logo {
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-right: 5px;
  }
  
  .logo img {
    object-fit: contain;
    height: 25px;
  }
```

Comment: Without having a complete example with the texts you mentioned my best guess would be to use the `background-image` property along with `background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;` and `background-position: center;` to set your image there

Comment: I mean the text & outside content in the other divs positioned below the image logo div

Comment: As the imgs are logos it will be important to always show the whole image, not allow them to be cropped or (worse) stretched, so follow @Parco advice and use contain to size them.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a simple `width:100%` in a contained space would do the trick.

```css
.logo-container{
border:1px solid #ccc;
padding:10px;
}

.logo-container img{
width:100%;
height:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='logo-container'>
<img src='https://picsum.photos/2000/3000' />
</div>
```